# jQuery setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a simple function that animates a bunch of images by crossfading them. A simple banner rotation. I set up the function so that calling `animateSlideshow("play")` it should set the timeout and start animating and by calling `animateSlideshow("stop")` it should stop.

When I call stop, however, the animation happens one more time. What is the cause for this one extra animation and how can I deal with it?

this calls the function on the bottom

```
function prevSlide(e){

    if(curHashIndex !== 0){

        $(prevBtn).off();

        // Stop the current slideshow
        animateSlideshow("stop");

        // Reset the current slideshow
        $("li.active .rightSlide > li").fadeOut(600).eq(0).fadeIn(600).addClass("actvImg");

        $(".rightSlides").animate({
            "left" : '+=345'
        }, 600, function(){
            $(prevBtn).on('click', prevSlide);
        });

        $(".leftSlides").animate({
            "left" : '+=417'
        }, 600);

        // Activate the new slide
        $(".rightSlides li.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
        activeSlide = $(".rightSlides li.active");
        total = $(".rightSlides li.active .rightSlide > li").length;

        // Start slideshow on the new slide
        var delay = setTimeout(animateSlideshow("play"), 10000);

        updateHash();
    }

}





function animateSlideshow(action){

    if(action === "play"){
        $(activeSlide).data('animateSlideshow', 
            setTimeout(function(){

                if( $(actvImg).index() === total - 1 ){
                    $(actvImg).fadeOut(animationSpeed).removeClass("actvImg").siblings().eq(0).fadeIn(animationSpeed).addClass("actvImg");
                }else{
                    $(actvImg).fadeOut(animationSpeed).removeClass("actvImg").next().fadeIn(animationSpeed).addClass("actvImg");
                }

                actvImg = $(".rightSlides li.active .rightSlide > li.actvImg");
                actvImgIndx = $(actvImg).index();
                updateBreadcrumbs();
                animateSlideshow("play")

            }, animationTimeout)
        );
    }else{
        clearTimeout($(activeSlide).data('animateSlideshow'));
    };

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use setInterval() / clearInterval() rather than recalling the function using setTimeout().

```
function animateSlideshow(action){

if(action === "play"){
    $(activeSlide).data('animateSlideshow', 
        setInterval(function(){

            if( $(actvImg).index() === total - 1 ){
                $(actvImg).fadeOut(animationSpeed).removeClass("actvImg").siblings().eq(0).fadeIn(animationSpeed).addClass("actvImg");
            }else{
                $(actvImg).fadeOut(animationSpeed).removeClass("actvImg").next().fadeIn(animationSpeed).addClass("actvImg");
            }

            actvImg = $(".rightSlides li.active .rightSlide > li.actvImg");
            actvImgIndx = $(actvImg).index();
            updateBreadcrumbs();

        }, animationTimeout);
    );
}else{
    clearInterval($(activeSlide).data('animateSlideshow'));
};

};
```

Comment: It's been bearing the same results for me, actually. I initially wrote the function with intervals.

Comment: It should at least keep you from rebinding the data with the setTimeout() - we may need to see what is calling this function or know if there is a certain browser this issue appears in. This function should work as expected.

Comment: I updated my first post with the function that makes the call.

Comment: I figured it out, had a variable definition that stuck around for longer than it should have.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why it is failing for you, but I tried a similar demo and it worked for me..

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5VCMa/1/)** here

Additionally, I used [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the current animation. You can use it if you want to stop the current animation on that object.

Comment: Must be a mistake elsewhere in my code. I'll try adding stop.